# How to add xs:occurs attribute group to my element declaration?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am defining a complex element `sequence_T` that I would like to add minOccurs/maxOccurs attributes to that have the same semantics as those of the occurs group defined in https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd, but I am encountering difficulties that seem to exceed my current skill level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://versionschema.org/xmlns"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsv="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" xsv:minVersion="1.1"
    xmlns:vs="http://versionschema.org/xmlns" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xml:lang="en" version="Experimental.0 {VSchemaInDev.0}"
    >

    <xsd:complexType name="sequence_T" final="#all">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Declares an ordered list of elements.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:group ref="vs:baseelementsGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:controlGroup"/>
                <xsd:group ref="vs:ruleelementsGroup"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="vs:annotationsAttributeGroup"/>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="xsd:occurs"/>

    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I am getting "cannot resolve the name 'xsd:occurs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component". Any clues how to add these attributes?

I do have this work-around:

```
<xsd:attributeGroup name="minmaxAttributesGroup">

    <xsd:attribute name="minOccurs" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" default="1"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="maxOccurs" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" default="1"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="maxOccursUnbounded" type="xsd:boolean" default="false"/>

</xsd:attributeGroup>
```

But `maxOccursUnbounded="true"` is not as semantically clean as `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to achieve. It would seem that you have declared a type, and what you are trying to define is an `xsd:sequence` of element of that type, which would have the min/max occurs. That would be something that is defined on the element that would contain that sequence of elements.

Comment: The crux of my problem is defining the attributes so I can add them to the elements as I go. How to define maxOccurs so that it can be either a non-negative integer or "unbounded"?  I tried to follow the pattern for the occurs attribute group in https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd, but I think that relies on some magic.

Comment: I can't just add the xsd:occurs element group to me elements. If there's a way to correctly reference that, I'd like to know what it is, because I think the XMLSchema.xsd reference can't actually be processed by compliant tooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your initial issue, I think you need to `xsd:import` "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" as soon as you reference constructs it defines that are not implicitly available in every schema definition (cf. https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#simple-ur-type-itself).

I found that `xmllint` would happily validate an XML document using your initial schema if it contained the following additional line :

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"/>`
```

Regarding your workaround, in order to allow `unbounded` as a valid value for `maxOccurs`, you have to define a local type inspired from `xsd:allNNI` which is not usable as-is (you'll hit the same issue as using `xsd:occurs` when trying to use it without `xs:import`) and the use that type for (your own) `maxOccurs`:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="allNNI">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>for maxOccurs</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:nonNegativeInteger">
        <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
                <xsd:enumeration value="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:union>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:attributeGroup name="minmaxAttributesGroup">
    <xsd:attribute name="minOccurs" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger" default="1"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="maxOccurs" type="vs:allNNI" default="1"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>
```

Comment: Ha! I was close at least once ;).  That did it and I didn't need the import.  Thank you so much!

Comment: But then I decided to apply the DRY principle, used the import and dropped my minmaxAttributesGroup.